# default radio button selection using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is what i wanted to accomplish. I have 2 sets of radio buttons. Radio button at the same index position in the 2 sets should not be selected at the same time. If a user tries to select, it must show alert and the defaut radio button must be selected.
Here is my html

```
<input type="radio" name="A" checked="checked" onclick="return check();" />
   <input type="radio" name="A" onclick="return check();" />

   <br />
[enter link description here][1]
   <input type="radio" name="B"  onclick="return check();" />
   <input type="radio" name="B" checked="checked" onclick="return check();" />
```

Here is the JS

```
 function check() {
        //logic to check for duplicate selection
        alert('Its already selected');
        return false;
    }
```

It works perfectly fine. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cGxV8/)

Now suppose, one of the check box is not selected , say in the second set. If the user selects first radio button from second set, which is already selected in the first, an alert is showed. But the radio button remains selected.

Here is modified html

```
    <input type="radio" name="A" checked="checked" onclick="return check();" />
   <input type="radio" name="A" onclick="return check();" />

   <br />

   <input type="radio" name="B"  onclick="return check();" />
   <input type="radio" name="B" onclick="return check();" />
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ekdf2/6/).

***NOTE:*** i can't use jquery since the code is already a part of some legacy application

Comment: onclick="return check();" <-- what are you returning the value to? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: returning false make the selected radio button to undo the selection to what it was previously if false...

Answer (score 0):

This works without jQuery:

```
// get all elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

/**
 * check if radio with own name is already selected
 * if so return false
 */
function check(){

  var selected_name = this.name,
      selected_value = this.value,
      is_valid = true;

  // compare with all other elements
  for(var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      var el = elements[j];

      // does the elemenet have the same name AND is already selected?
      if(el.name != selected_name && el.value == selected_value && el.checked){
        // if so, selection is not valid anymore
        alert('nope')

        // check current group for previous selection
        is_valid = false;
        break;
      }
  };

  return is_valid;
}

/**
 * bind your elements to the check-routine
 */
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].onmousedown = check;
}
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cGxV8/4/)

Does this fit your needs?

Comment: You noticed that A and B are besides?

Comment: As you asked you can not select a radio that is already selected elsewhere - is this not what you are asking for?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49970/discussion-between-nils-and-ijay)

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you should arrange the radio buttons in the other way:

```
 <input type="radio" name="col1" value="A1">
 <input type="radio" name="col2" value="A2">
 <input type="radio" name="col3" value="A3">

 <input type="radio" name="col1" value="B1">
 <input type="radio" name="col2" value="B2">
 <input type="radio" name="col3" value="B3">
```

That means the user only can select one value in each column without the obtrusive alert or javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Give value to your radios:

```
<input type="radio" name="A" checked="checked" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="A" value="2" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="B"  value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="B" value="2" />
```

Then you can do as follows:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
  radios[i].addEventListener('click', check);
}

function check(){
  var index= this.value-1;
  if(this.name=='A'){
     if(document.getElementsByName('B')[index].checked){
        alert('already selectedin other set'); 
        var otherIndex= (index==0)?1:0;
        var other = document.getElementsByName("A")[otherIndex];
        other.checked= true;
        }
    }
    else{
       if(document.getElementsByName('A')[index].checked){
           alert('already selected in other set');
           var otherIndex= (index==0)?1:0;
           var other = document.getElementsByName("B")[otherIndex]; 
           other.checked= true;
        }
   }
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Ekdf2/15/)

Comment: i'm not the down voter, but this doesn't work.It shows an alert but doesn't toggle back to its previous state as is shown in my first demo